# How to help people who have lost their cookie?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes see unregistered users losing their cookie and editing their original question with another account. For example, in [this edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/285286), you can see it.

So, what should we do to help them? Is there a way for 2 unregistered accounts to be merged? I know of the way you can merge to *registered* accounts, but does it work for *unregistered* accounts as well?

Comment: I agree it would be REALLY useful to be able to merge unregistered accounts, but unlike registered accounts there is no way to PROVE it's the same person on the other end of the line, even an IP address is no guarantee (shared IPs, Dynamic IPs, public computers), it's important to respect the original account holder's rights. A silverlining would be it provides incentive to register. To me, even what this example user did (edited from another account) is not acceptable, because the new information should be treated as if it comes from a different person. Am I coming off snarky?

Comment: @RobinHood I agree that it is very difficult to actually find out whether the editor is the same person, but in this particular case, I think it was acceptable because it is a small amount of info, and I know it's a response to my comment. In cases where a lot of text is added/removed and the meaning is changed, it is more likely it is a random user. Also, the OP user id was `370412` and the editor `370434` - they're very close which probably means the OP figured out he lost his cookie and reregistered.

Comment: Here, I have a spare one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Pepperidge-Farm-Nantucket-Cookie.jpg (sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, other than suggesting they use the contact us link, and asking SE to merge the accounts in questions, there is *nothing* you can do. And yes, this works with unregistered accounts as well.

Comment: That's too bad. I'd make a feature-request, but I have no idea what to request! I can't think of anything that could help people without their cookie!

Comment: @ṧнʊß How about a box in the ??moderator area?? where they can enter the 2 account user id's (not names), and click a merge button?

Comment: Mods used to be able to do it, but there's some potential underlying issues so... its dev only.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192725/allow-community-moderators-to-merge-accounts-where-one-is-unregistered That's the full, official story.

Comment: ah, ok. thank you

Comment: Speaking of which, it used to be that mods would merge spam users into a special user called the "deposit" user, but they no longer do, both because of this, and because "there are better methods now than merging into the deposit user".

Comment: @JourneymanGeek actually, to merge accounts automagically, you need at least one registered account.

Comment: Oh true. You *still* need to get a dev to do it tho

Answer (score -4):

I usually recommend Pepto-Bismol or Kaopectate for someone who is losing their cookies.

Comment: this should really be a comment.